# How to disable automatic package installation / upgrade in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, package

I don't want Visual Studio to add any files to my solution and I can add necessary references myself.

How can I disable this entirely?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new solution, only select the language you want to code in for this project and blank project. This will create a project with nothing inside so that you can add anything you want.

Comment: Hmm, that's not exactly what I've asked and it will not prevent automatic package installation. I know how to create an empty project. Here is the scenario: I add a web api controller to my project and VS adds this annoying `packages` folder and downloads gazillion of files when what's really necessary is to add a couple of dlls. I have to go and clean up references and delete all that clutter afterwards.

Comment: You want which packages to be disabled for example ?

Comment: I need to disable any automatic installation, but be able to install them manually if I need.